# Parse the following JSON using google apps script

Tags: json, google-apps-script

-- Hi everyone, It's been now several days I'm trying to parse the following JSON using google apps script.

```
[
{
"NOMBRE": "ViejosNoUsarEl Quebrachal",
"ACTIVO": false,
"CODIGO": "ViejosNoUsarQUEB",
"CALLE": null,
"NUMERO": null,
"PROVINCIA": "Jujuy",
"LOCALIDAD": "EL MORRO",
"ZONA": null,
"SUPERFICIE": 3900,
"CODIGOEXTERNO": ""
},
{
"NOMBRE": "ViejoNoUsarSanta Teresa",
"ACTIVO": false,
"CODIGO": "ViejoNoUsarST",
"CALLE": null,
"NUMERO": null,
"PROVINCIA": "San Luis",
"LOCALIDAD": "Villa MercedesOLD",
"ZONA": "Oeste",
"SUPERFICIE": 3700,
"CODIGOEXTERNO": ""
},
{
"NOMBRE": "ViejosNoUsarGil",
"ACTIVO": false,
"CODIGO": "ViejosNoUsarGIL",
"CALLE": null,
"NUMERO": null,
"PROVINCIA": "Cordoba",
"LOCALIDAD": "9 DE JULIO",
"ZONA": "Oeste",
"SUPERFICIE": 200,
"CODIGOEXTERNO": ""
},
{
"NOMBRE": "ViejosNoUsarDon Manuel",
"ACTIVO": false,
"CODIGO": "ViejosNoUsarDM",
"CALLE": null,
"NUMERO": null,
"PROVINCIA": "Cordoba",
"LOCALIDAD": "9 DE JULIO",
"ZONA": "Oeste",
"SUPERFICIE": 400,
"CODIGOEXTERNO": ""
}
]
```

The GET response is giving me the JSON as I posted it.

Using google apps script I want to add on a google sheet as much rows as objects are in the array.

In this case there would be 4 google sheet rows. I want to parse only the values of the properties.

As an example, the first row would look like this:

ViejosNoUsarEl Quebrachal | false | ViejosNoUsarQUEB | null | null | Jujuy | EL MORRO | null | 3900 |

I want to focus on this question on the pasrsing matter, not on the adding the rows to the google sheet yet.

The problem is that I cant get the dot notation to extract the values I want.

For example, Logger.log(response.provincia); prints "Information null".

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing sample data and `For example, Logger.log(response.provincia); prints "Information null".`, I thought that the reason for your issue is due to that you are trying to retrieve the values from an array using `response.provincia`. In this case, it is required to be `response[i].PROVINCIA`. `i` is the index of an array. If you want to retrieve the value of "PROVINCIA" of the 1st element of the array, you can use `response[0].PROVINCIA`. From your showing data, `provincia` is required to be `PROVINCIA`. When `response[0].provincia` is run, `undefined` is returned. Please be careful about this.
- When you want to retrieve the values like `ViejosNoUsarEl Quebrachal | false | ViejosNoUsarQUEB | null | null | Jujuy | EL MORRO | null | 3900 |` in order, in this case, the values are retrieved by preparing the keys in order.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
const keys = ["NOMBRE", "ACTIVO", "CODIGO", "CALLE", "NUMERO", "PROVINCIA", "LOCALIDAD", "ZONA", "SUPERFICIE", "CODIGOEXTERNO"];

const response = [
  {
    "NOMBRE": "ViejosNoUsarEl Quebrachal",
    "ACTIVO": false,
    "CODIGO": "ViejosNoUsarQUEB",
    "CALLE": null,
    "NUMERO": null,
    "PROVINCIA": "Jujuy",
    "LOCALIDAD": "EL MORRO",
    "ZONA": null,
    "SUPERFICIE": 3900,
    "CODIGOEXTERNO": ""
  },
  {
    "NOMBRE": "ViejoNoUsarSanta Teresa",
    "ACTIVO": false,
    "CODIGO": "ViejoNoUsarST",
    "CALLE": null,
    "NUMERO": null,
    "PROVINCIA": "San Luis",
    "LOCALIDAD": "Villa MercedesOLD",
    "ZONA": "Oeste",
    "SUPERFICIE": 3700,
    "CODIGOEXTERNO": ""
  },
  {
    "NOMBRE": "ViejosNoUsarGil",
    "ACTIVO": false,
    "CODIGO": "ViejosNoUsarGIL",
    "CALLE": null,
    "NUMERO": null,
    "PROVINCIA": "Cordoba",
    "LOCALIDAD": "9 DE JULIO",
    "ZONA": "Oeste",
    "SUPERFICIE": 200,
    "CODIGOEXTERNO": ""
  },
  {
    "NOMBRE": "ViejosNoUsarDon Manuel",
    "ACTIVO": false,
    "CODIGO": "ViejosNoUsarDM",
    "CALLE": null,
    "NUMERO": null,
    "PROVINCIA": "Cordoba",
    "LOCALIDAD": "9 DE JULIO",
    "ZONA": "Oeste",
    "SUPERFICIE": 400,
    "CODIGOEXTERNO": ""
  }
];
const values = response.map(o => keys.map(h => o[h]));
console.log(values)
```

- When this script is run, the values are returned as the 2-dimensional array. This can be used for putting to the Spreadsheet using `setValues`.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)